# Redirect create common rules

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

There are a few redirect rules for pages with query strings

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PAGEN_1=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/$ http://www.mysite.ru/news/$ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/$ http://www.mysite.ru/news/$ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/$ http://www.mysite.ru/news/?PAGEN_1=2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/$ http://www.mysite.ru/news/?PAGEN_1=3 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=4 [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/$ http://www.mysite.ru/news/?PAGEN_1=4 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PAGEN_1=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/2/$ http://www.mysite.ru/articles/2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/2/$ http://www.mysite.ru/articles/2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/2/$ http://www.mysite.ru/articles/2/?PAGEN_1=2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/2/$ http://www.mysite.ru/articles/2/?PAGEN_1=3 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=4 [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/2/$ http://www.mysite.ru/articles/2/?PAGEN_1=4 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=5 [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/2/$ http://www.mysite.ru/articles/2/?PAGEN_1=5 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=6 [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/2/$ http://www.mysite.ru/articles/2/?PAGEN_1=6 [R=301,L]
```

Is there any way to write these rules in common, not for every query string?

**UPD**
I used this code

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PAGEN_1=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/$ http://www.mysite.ru/news/$ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/$ http://www.mysite.ru/news/$ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=([0-9]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.ru/news/?PAGEN_1=%1 [R=301,L]




RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PAGEN_1=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/2/$ http://www.mysite.ru/articles/2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/2/$ http://www.mysite.ru/articles/2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=([0-9]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/2/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.ru/articles/2/?PAGEN_1=%1 [R=301,L]
```

but I'm not sure about it. It works but I think maybe it should be simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)PAGEN_1=1(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/?$ http://www.mysite.ru/news/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=(\d+)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/?$ http://www.mysite.ru/news/?PAGEN_1=%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)PAGEN_1=1(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/(\d+)/?$ http://www.mysite.ru/articles/$1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=(\d+)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/(\d+)/?$ http://www.mysite.ru/articles/$1/?PAGEN_1=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried to use your code, but I get error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: `http://www.mysite.ru` is the same domain ? Why do you try to redirect to the same site. It's because you add one `&` after `?`?

Comment: Yes, I need to redirect to the same site because of `&` after `?` (it's not my idea, the seo-manager said to do that). Thanks a lot for help, all works just fine!